# I set wp_set_auth_cookie but wp_validate_auth_cookie returns false

Tags: wp-admin

I am trying to implement custom login on wordpress. To do this:

- I have added an action to the [wp_loaded](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_loaded/) event in which I do my custom authentication and once user is authenticated, I have following code to set the auth cookie:

```
wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
```

Now if I test this code with `/wp-admin` as the URL this is what happens:

- the code is executed and I verified `wp_set_auth_cookie` is called
- subsequently there is a call to [auth_redirect](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.5/wp-admin/admin.php#L99) from admin.php
- Within this call there is a call to [wp_validate_auth_cookie](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_validate_auth_cookie/) and that fails to pass

The result is that user is redirected to login page whereas this should not happen. I want `wp_validate_auth_cookie` to pass. I think the reason for this behavior is that `wp_set_auth_cookie` will set the cookie in the HTTP response and its only in any *subsequent* request from the browser that the cookie will be set in the HTTP request. However that ruins my test case.

Is there any way to:

- suppress the `auth_redirect` from admin.php
- or make `wp_validate_auth_cookie` return true

or anything else that can be done so that user is not redirected to login page when they try to access `/wp-admin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the login works without having to reload the page (or redirect to somewhere on the site), then you would want to immediately set both the *auth and logged-in cookies*, i.e. set them in the superglobal `$_COOKIE` array. And you can do that via the [`set_auth_cookie`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/set_auth_cookie/) and [`set_logged_in_cookie`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/set_logged_in_cookie/) hooks:

```php
add_action( 'set_auth_cookie', function ( $cookie ) {
    $cookie_name = is_ssl() ? SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE : AUTH_COOKIE;
    $_COOKIE[ $cookie_name ] = $cookie;
} );

add_action( 'set_logged_in_cookie', function ( $cookie ) {
    $_COOKIE[ LOGGED_IN_COOKIE ] = $cookie;
} );
```

Comment: Thanks. You clearly are a wordpress expert!